# torch.mul causes param.grad to be NoneType

Tags: pytorch

```
class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, D_u, D_i, D_t, D_m):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.lin_u = nn.Linear(D_u, 1)
        self.lin_i = nn.Linear(D_i, 1)
        self.lin_t = nn.Linear(D_t, 1)
        self.lin_m = nn.Linear(D_m, 1)
      
        self.output = nn.Linear(4, 1)

    def forward(self, args):
        (u, i, t, m) = args
        u = F.relu(self.lin_u(u))
        i = F.relu(self.lin_i(i))
        t = F.relu(self.lin_t(t))
        m = F.relu(self.lin_m(m))
        out = torch.mul(u, i)
        out = torch.mul(out, t)
        out = torch.mul(out, m)
        return out
```

I have this simple model class which has four inputs, each with its own linear layer. I want the output to be the product of the four nodes, but for some reason no matter how I multiply them (with torch.mul or *), the grad is always Nonetype:

```
model = Net(N, 3, T, 1)
u_block, i_block, t_block, m_block, y_block = get_data_new(data)

loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')

learning_rate = 1e-4
for t in range(5000):
    y_pred = model((u_block, i_block, t_block, m_block))

    loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_block)
    if t % 100 == 99:
        print(t, loss.item())

    model.zero_grad()

    loss.backward()

    with torch.no_grad():
        for param in model.parameters():
          param -= learning_rate * param.grad
```

```
TypeError                                 
--->   param -= learning_rate * param.grad

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

I've set the inputs to requires_grad=True, I think the issue is that out is not a leaf and therefore has no gradient, but I don't know how to fix this.

Edit:

The data u_block, i_block, t_block, m_block, y_block are shown below. u_block, i_block, and t_block are one-hot vectors.

````
u_block:  tensor([[1., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        ...,
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 1.]], requires_grad=True)
i_block:  tensor([[1., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0.],
        ...,
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.]], requires_grad=True)
t_block:  tensor([[1., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        ...,
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 1.]], requires_grad=True)
m_block:  tensor([[ 0.0335],
        [ 0.0000],
        [ 0.0000],
        ...,
        [ 0.1515],
        [-0.2261],
        [-0.0402]], requires_grad=True)
y_block:  tensor([[ 0.0000],
        [ 0.0000],
        [ 0.0000],
        ...,
        [-0.2261],
        [-0.0402],
        [-0.1318]], requires_grad=True)```
````

Comment: provide sample data that you are passing in ```get_data_new(data)``` or ```u_block, i_block, t_block, m_block, y_block```

Comment: They were each created from ```torch.tensor(arr.astype(np.float32), requires_grad=True)```, where arr is a numpy array.

Comment: provide ```arr```

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes. You are not using `self.output` so I have commented. This makes gradient None as you are not using it in forward pass and the layer has requires_grad=True by default.

```
class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, D_u, D_i, D_t, D_m):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.lin_u = nn.Linear(D_u, 1)
        self.lin_i = nn.Linear(D_i, 1)
        self.lin_t = nn.Linear(D_t, 1)
        self.lin_m = nn.Linear(D_m, 1)
      
        # self.output = nn.Linear(4, 1)

    def forward(self, args):
        (u, i, t, m) = args
        u = F.relu(self.lin_u(u))
        i = F.relu(self.lin_i(i))
        t = F.relu(self.lin_t(t))
        m = F.relu(self.lin_m(m))
        out = torch.mul(u, i)
        out = torch.mul(out, t)
        out = torch.mul(out, m)
        return out
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Also, I have some suggestions,

1. change the name args to some other name or if you want to use it then use it in its full glory by changing to *args.
2. for input don't put requires_grad argument. as it will compute d_Loss/ d_input. (Do this only if its not your intention)